# De-greedifying a regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex, greedy, non-greedy

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will convert a full path filename to a short filename for a given filetype, minus the file extension.

For example, I'm trying to get just the name of the .bar file from a string using

```
re.search('/(.*?)\.bar$', '/def_params/param_1M56/param/foo.bar')
```

According to the Python re docs, `*?` is the ungreedy version of `*`, so I was expecting to get

```
'foo'
```

returned for `match.group(1)` but instead I got

```
'def_params/param_1M56/param/foo'
```

What am I missing here about greediness?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're missing isn't so much about greediness as about regular expression engines:  they work from left to right, so the `/` matches as early as possible and the `.*?` is then forced to work from there.  In this case, the best regex doesn't involve greediness at all (you need backtracking for that to work; it will, but could take a really long time to run if there are a lot of slashes), but a more explicit pattern:

```
'/([^/]*)\.bar$'
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest changing your regex so that it doesn't rely on greedyness.

You want only the filename before the extension `.bar` and everything after the final `/`. This should do:

```
re.search(`/[^/]*\.bar$`, '/def_params/param_1M56/param/foo.bar')
```

What this does is it matches `/`, then zero or more characters (as much as possible) that are **not** `/` and then `.bar`.

Comment: the `.` in your regex is matching anything, instead of the `.` of the extension file. Make sure you're escaping the `.` with `\.`

Comment: Woops :) Edited. I hope that this wasn't the reason for the downvote though, since it's irrelevant for the problem.

Comment: upvoted again ;) although it could be irrelevant for this problem, maybe the OP wants to use it (now, or later) to match files with extension `bar` or something, and that one would match `.abar` too, for example :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't claim to understand the non-greedy operators all that well, but a solution for that particular problem would be to use ([^/]*?)

Answer (score 0):

The regular expressions starts from the right. Put a .* at the start and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I like regex but there is no need of one here.

```
path = '/def_params/param_1M56/param/foo.bar'
print  path.rsplit('/',1)[1].rsplit('.')[0]

path = '/def_params/param_1M56/param/fululu'
print  path.rsplit('/',1)[1].rsplit('.')[0]

path = '/def_params/param_1M56/param/one.before.two.dat'
print  path.rsplit('/',1)[1].rsplit('.',1)[0]
```

result

```
foo
fululu
one.before.two
```

Comment: I actually figured that one out right after I posted the question. Still wanted to know about the nature of greediness, tho. You can also just use `path.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Other people have answered the regex question, but in this case there's a more efficient way than regex:

```
file_name = path[path.rindex('/')+1 : path.rindex('.')]
```

Answer (score -1):

try this one on for size:

match = re.search('.*/(.*?).bar$', '/def_params/param_1M56/param/foo.bar')

Comment: If you're already using `'.*/`, I don't think you really need `.*?`. `.*` will work too :) Could you edit your question so I can upvote you again?